# Android download file from google cloud storage

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

I can upload image to google storage, now i'm trying to download this file but i have a nullPointerException

```
            try {
                List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
                scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);
                httpTransport = new com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport();

                // agarro la key y la convierto en un file
                AssetManager am = mContext.getAssets();
                InputStream inputStream = am.open(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.storage_p12_key_path)); // you
                File file = stream2file(inputStream);

                // Google Credentianls
                GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                        .setServiceAccountId(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.storage_mail_id))
                        .setServiceAccountScopes((scopes)).setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file).build();
                String URI = null;
                HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(credential);


                GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(URI);
                HttpRequest getRequest;
                getRequest = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);

                com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse response =     getRequest.execute();
                String content = response.parseAsString();
                Log.d("debug", "response is:" + response.getStatusCode());
                Log.d("debug", "response content is:" + content);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

On this line getRequest.execute(); i get nullPointer exception

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at your stack trace, I can't be sure, but I presume it's because URI is null. This bit:

```
String URI = null;
GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(URI); //url is to a null URI
HttpRequest getRequest = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url); //getRequest for a null URL
getRequest.execute() // call to a null URI.
```

Comment: i corret it, but now i have nullPointerException here 
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse response = getRequest.execute();

thank's for your response